# how to call json file into html

Tags: jquery, json

I have json file and I want to call images and heading from json file. The requirement is when I click on image 1 then first image and heading should append on div 1 and when I click other link it should append appropriate image. My json file contains

```
[
    {
        "image" : "images/test1.png",
        "heading" : "Careers"
    },
    {
        "image" : "images/item-2.png",
        "heading" : "Contact Us"
    },
    {
        "image" : "images/item-3.png",
        "heading" : "About Us"
    }
]
```

My code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        var txt= $(this).text()
        $.getJSON("myson.js",function(result) {
            $.each(result, function(i, field) {
                if(txt.indexOf('1')>-1) {

                }

                else if(txt.indexOf('2')>-1) {

                }
                else {

                }

            });
        });
    });
});
```

Html

```
<a href='#'>Image 1</a>
<a href='#'>Image 2</a>
<a href='#'>Image 3</a>

<div style="border:solid 1px #000; width:200px; height:200px">
    <div id='heading'></div>
    <div id='image'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you don't want to load the JSON file each time you click an image. You want to load the JSON file once at the beginning and store the information as a variable object.

Then when you click the image, you just grab the information out of the variable object and put the info into the "heading" and "image" divs.

Also, you should give your  tags some sort of value attribute (like an **id** or just make one up like **value**) so that in the event you decide you want to switch something in the future and you don't have to re-write / re-order your json file.

For the sake of the code below, change your 3  tags to look like this:

```
<a val='0' href='#'>Image 1</a>
<a val='1' href='#'>Image 2</a>
<a val='2' href='#'>Image 3</a>
```

JS:

```
$().ready(
    function(){
        var dataSet;
        $.getJSON("myson.js",function(d){}).success(processData);

        function processData(ds){
            dataSet = ds;
        }

        $("a").click(function(){
            $("#heading").empty().html(dataSet[Number($(this).attr('val'))].heading);
            $("#image").empty().html("<img src='" + dataSet[Number($(this).attr('val'))].image + "' />");
        }
    }
);
```

Give that a try